# Freezing assets and sending them back to the original issuer

Tags: transactions

In a disputed transaction, after freezing the assets, how can you send the assets back to the original issuer?

Say for instance, you meant to send $100 but instead sent $1,000.  Is there a way to reverse the transaction by freezing the assets?

Comment: Is this from the perspective of an anchor overseeing a transaction between their customers, or from an individual sending assets to another individual account? If you're referring to an anchor overseeing a transaction, there are some architecture options where you could issue transactions on behalf of your customers. You could "reverse" an incorrect transaction by creating another transaction of equal value in the opposite direction in this case.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible. If you are the issuer, you can set the [AUTHORIZATION_REVOCABLE](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#revoking-access) attribute on the issuer account. However, you won't be able to revert the particular transaction, only to freeze the entire trustline.

[Multi-sig](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html) is the only way to implement disputable or escrow transactions on-chain.